# XGBoost: OS Error : [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363 running XGBClassifier with large dataset, CPU Mode

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

Getting this error while trying to run XGBClassifier and GridsearchCV for hyperparameter optimization. I have seen this issue being opened in Github but closed and marked resolved but no solution provided. Has anyone actually found a soultion to this error?

My dataset:

```
X = np array with 350000 rows and 1715 columns (after one hot encoding)
y = 350000 rows and 1 column (target)
```

My Code:

```
X = train.drop(['Breakage'], axis=1,)  #features (read from dataframe)
y = train['Breakage']    #target (read from dataframe)

X= X.as_matrix()    #convert to np array
y= y.as_matrix()    #convert to np array
y = np.reshape(y,(-1, 1))    #reshape array

X = X.astype('uint8')  #Change dtype to avoid overcommmit error in windows
y = y.astype('uint8')  #Change dtype to avoid overcommmit error in windows

#define estimators and learning rate
model = XGBClassifier()
n_estimators = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
learning_rate = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1]

# GRidSearchCV
param_grid = dict(learning_rate=learning_rate, n_estimators=n_estimators)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=7)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=kfold)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X,y)
```

The output Error:

```
OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem as yours.
This answer will help you.
[Windows Error using XGBoost with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804208/windows-error-using-xgboost-with-python)
Change the 'xgb.fit()' sklearn api to 'xgb.train()' will solve this problem.

Comment: What answer? The link does not point to an answer but to a question. Also `xgb.fit()` could not be found here or on the other question. Please edit your answer so it's clear. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26569369).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was something to do with the installation of xgboost.

I was using code that already worked before, and although there was a lot of memory usage, it is not a memory error.

What worked for me was

1. Close the IDE
2. Uninstall xgboost
3. Upgrade pip (not sure if necessary)
4. Reinstall xgboost
5. Rebuild and install python project
6. Run again

Source of inspiration from this question here:
[Windows Error 0xe06d7363 when using Cross Validation XGboost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364048/windows-error-0xe06d7363-when-using-cross-validation-xgboost)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used self-written libraries written in c++. It so happened that I forgot to catch an exception called inside the code, which led to this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).